# How can you differentiate between a user click and .click()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, event-handling, click

For the web application I've been developing, I've been utilizing Kendo UI so I don't have to write a bunch of components. I've got 6 grids located inside of a tabstrip with the `.Select()` tag applied so that there are checkboxes appearing within the grids. When you make a selection in grid 1, for example, it enables the tab containing grid 2. 
If you removed all of your selections from Grid 1, it would disable all the following grids. The other requirement is that it should also clear any of the selections you have made in these child grids.

I've been using this method in order to uncheck everything in a given grid:

```
function uncheckAll(gridID) {
    const inputString = gridID + " input[type='checkbox']:checked";
    const checked = $(inputString);
    const selectAll = $(gridID + " input[type='checkbox']:first")[0].checked;
    if (selectAll) {
        let checkedExcludingCheckAll = [];
        for (let i = 1; i < checked.length; i++) {
            checkedExcludingCheckAll.push(checked[i]);
        }
        for (row of checkedExcludingCheckAll) {
            row.click();
        }
    } else {
        for (row of checked) {
            row.click();
        }
    }
}
```

The code works exactly as intended. The problem is, when you deselect everything from a higher-level grid, because this code calls `click` events, it calls all the other event handlers of every other grid, and walks through each of the child grids (up to 5 of them) and deselects everything. Asymptotically, it's a bit of a nightmare.

I've modified my code at the end to only grab selections made in tabs that are **currently enabled.** Any selections present within a grid stored inside of a disabled tab are ignored, which means it is unnecessary for my code to walk through each of the grids and fire all of these events.

So, it would be really great if I could force `uncheckAll()` to **only** uncheck the items in the immediate child grid, and not fire all those unnecessary events. What is the best way to achieve this? I have looked into temporarily disabling the event handlers for the `row.click()` lines, but that led to some unexpected behaviors. What are my options here?

EDIT: More code examples. When `row.click()` is called, the `click` event runs into these event handlers that run the rest of the code.

```
function dataBound() {
   // this handler reads only the 'select all' box
   $('#Grid.k-checkbox:first').unbind('click').on('click', () => {
       // ...
       // function calls that call uncheckAll() within them if a condition is satisfied
   }
   // read in any checkbox in the grid that isn't the 'select all' box
   $('#Grid.k-checkbox:not(:first)').on('change', clickOneCheckbox);
}

function clickOneCheckbox() {
    // ...
    // function calls that call uncheckAll() within them if a condition is satisfied
}
```

Comment: I believe the issue is not that you're calling `click()` but rather the contents of your jQuery collections contain more elements than they should. It's hard to tell without a proper example.

Comment: I've included a little bit more code in the post. I can try to add more, but I'm not sure how much I want to add in fear of creating too much clutter.

Comment: A working example would be the best. It doesn't have to be full code but something that replicates your issue in faithful detail. From that extra JS I can only guess that the CSS selectors are too generic in the `dataBound` function and are toggling all the _"select all"_ boxes. One would think that those selectors would only return one item since you have an ID in the selector, but if you've re-used the ID (not good) then you'll get back multiple elements. Hard to know without seeing the markup.

Comment: Instead of triggering `click` events to uncheck... Change the `cheched` property. `$("checkboxSelector').prop("checked", false);` -- That won't trigger the other click handlers.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I'll mark you as the solution if you would like to submit a post rather a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of triggering `click` events to uncheck... Change the `cheched` **property**.

```
$("checkboxSelector").prop("checked", false);
```

That won't trigger the other `click` handlers. ;)